# Why doesn't make_unique work with unique_ptr::reset?

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr, c++14

I tried compiling some C++ code with VS2013, and `unique_ptr::reset()` doesn't seem to work with `make_unique()`; a small compilable repro code snippet follows:

```
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    unique_ptr<int[]> p = make_unique<int[]>(3);
    p.reset(make_unique<int[]>(10));    
}
```

Compiling from command-line:

> ```
> C:\Temp\CppTests>cl /EHsc /W4 /nologo test.cpp
> ```

These are the errors from the MSVC compiler:

> ```
> test.cpp(6) : error C2280: 'void std::unique_ptr<int [],std::default_delete<_Ty>
> >::reset<std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>>>(_Ptr2)' : attempting to
> reference a deleted function
>         with
>         [
>             _Ty=int []
> ,            _Ptr2=std::unique_ptr<int [],std::default_delete<int []>>
>         ]
>         C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\memory(16
> 23) : see declaration of 'std::unique_ptr<int [],std::default_delete<_Ty>>::rese
> t'
>         with
>         [
>             _Ty=int []
>         ]
> ```

However, the following code seems to compile fine:

```
p = make_unique<int[]>(10);
```

What is the reason of this behavior? Why does `unique_ptr::operator=()` work with `make_unique()`, but `unique_ptr::reset()` doesn't?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`reset()` takes a pointer.

What you seem to want is simple *move assignment*:

```
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    unique_ptr<int[]> p = make_unique<int[]>(3);
    p = make_unique<int[]>(10);    
}
```

some compilers might still like you to specify the `std::move()` there, but it's not strictly required.

Answer (score 12):

Because `std::unique_ptr::reset` expects a pointer to an object to be managed, not another `unique_ptr`. `make_unique` creates a `unique_ptr`.